# using nested functions in do.call in R

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I have a data.frame named *df* with one column named *Text*, consisting of some sentences, and I want to add a new column named *Length* equal to number of words in the *Text* column. So, my data.frame looks like this:

```
      Text
1. First sentence.
2. Second sentence that is a bit longer.
3. Third.
4. Fourth one is the longest one with 9 words.
```

And the desired data.frame should look like this:

```
      Text                                  Length
1. First sentence.                              2
2. Second sentence that is a bit longer.        7
3. Third.                                       1
4. Fourth one is the longest one with 9 words.  9
```

These are my tries:

```
df$Length <- length(do.call(strsplit(., " ")[[1]], as.list(df$Text)))
```

and

```
df$Length <- do.call(length(strsplit(., " ")[[1]]), as.list(df$Text))
```

Would you please help me understanding what should I do?

Comment: Try `df$Length <- sapply(strsplit(df$Text, " "), length)`

Comment: `df$length <- lengths(strsplit(as.character(df$Text), "\\s+"))`

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, it gave me: Error in strsplit(df$Text, " ") : non-character argument

Comment: Then you need to convert to a character first, as Ronak Shah demonstrates

Answer (score 2):

You could also user the purrr-package:

```
df %>%
 dplyr::mutate(Length = purrr::map_dbl(Text, ~ length(unlist(stringr::str_split(as.character(.), " ")))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Florian, it gave me: Error in strsplit(., " ") : non-character argument

Comment: Yes, not it works. I just need to assign it to my data.frame (by adding -> df at the end of the code). Thanks @Florian)